# Kotlin: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException in MutableList add element

Tags: java, algorithm, stack, kotlin

I'm implementing a stack algorithm for study purpose in Kotlin

```
class Stack<T:Comparable<T>>(list:MutableList<T>) {

    var items: MutableList<T> = list


    fun isEmpty():Boolean = this.items.isEmpty()

    fun count():Int = this.items.count()

    fun push(element:T) {
        val position = this.count()
        this.items.add(position, element)
    }

    override  fun toString() = this.items.toString()

    fun pop():T? {
        if (this.isEmpty()) {
            return null
        } else {
            val item =  this.items.count() - 1
            return this.items.removeAt(item)
        }
    }

    fun peek():T? {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null
        } else {
            return this.items[this.items.count() - 1]
        }
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to execute using this code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

        var initialValue = listOf<Int>(10) as MutableList<Int>
        var stack = Stack<Int>(initialValue)
          stack.push(22)
        println(stack.count())
        println(stack.isEmpty())
        println(stack.pop())
        println(stack.count())
        println(stack.isEmpty())

    }
```

When I run the code I receive this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
at Stack.push(Stack.kt:17)
at StackKt.main(Stack.kt:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

This is related with the follow line that is implemented in   ***push(element:T)*** method:

```
 this.items.add(position, element)
```

The most weird thing is that I used a very similar code implementing a [orderedArray](https://github.com/gazolla/Kotlin-Algorithm/tree/master/OrderedArray) and it works perfectly.

Do you have any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`listOf<Int>` is not truly mutable. According to [the doc](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html):

> `fun <T> listOf(vararg elements: T): List<T> (source)`
>   Returns a new read-only list of given elements. The returned list is
>   serializable (JVM).

You should use [`mutableListOf<>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html) instead.

The reason why `as MutableList` is permitted here is because `listOf(10)` returns `Collections.singletonList(10)` which returns a `java.util.List` (which Kotlin assumes implements the `kotlin.collections.MutableList` interface). So the compiler does not know it's not really mutable until the mutating method is called at runtime and throws the exception.

Comment: So the solution is,  in the main method,  set  initialvalue with mutableListOf instead of listOf, right ?

Comment: The explanation why the cast is legal goes as follows: `List` is an interface and `MutableList` is an interface that extends `List`. Therefore casting from `List` to `MutableList`  is legal but it can and will crash at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Kirill !

Comment: @KirillRakhman That's true that the cast is allowed at compile time, but it is because `listOf` returns a `java.util.List` which implements `kotlin.collections.MutableList` interface. So it does not crash at the cast but rather at the call to `add`, when the implementation throws an exception.

Comment: Kotlin's `List` and `MutableList` are both mapped to `java.util.List` at compile time and don't exist at runtime at all.

Answer (score 7):

You can fix this by calling toMutableList() api rather than using smart cast (as).

Try: var initialValue = listOf< Int >(10).toMutableList()

Below is a working example:

```
fun main(){
    val x : List<String> = listOf("foo", "bar", "baz")
    //val y: MutableList<String> = x as MutableList<String> throws UnsupportedOperationException
    val y: MutableList<String> = x.toMutableList()
    y.add("sha")
    println(y) // [foo, bar, baz, sha]
}
```